# Having issues with large numbers in R

Tags: r

I am assigning a large odd number to a variable (1126605209290117121) and it is being shown as (1126605209290117120) [observe the last digit] in the environment. But assigning a large even number is represented correctly. Can someone explain why?

```r
a = 1126605209290117121
print(as.character(a))
[1] "1126605209290117120"
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `nchar(a) > .Machine$sizeof.longdouble` - https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/zMachine.html

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the internet I learned that R still has only 32-bit integers.
[This blog post in R Bloggers summarises the problem clearly](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-in-a-64-bit-world/)

Comment: It has 64 bit doubles that can represent a larger range of integers, but even this has limits. You might want to consider an arbitrary precision package such as gmp or Rmpfr.